# Getting rid of the spacing between logo and menu

Tags: wordpress, menu, header

Does anyone know how to get rid of the spacing between the logo on the top left and the menu bar under it? I would like them to align on top of each other. This my website http://www.bigredfro.com

I made a child theme and tried changing some of the code in the css.style file but this theme is a little more complicated then what I have worked with before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this into my customs css code and it worked

.td-header-sp-logo img, .td-header-so-logo, .td-header-sp-ads {

margin-bottom: 0px;

}